# Why when an Android activity is killed does the app still run in memory?

Tags: android-activity

Why, when an Android activity is killed does the app still run in memory?

I've read postings on stackoverflow and the Android documentation but cannot find the answer.

Comment: Hi Mike, can you pause with adding the rational tag questions. The tag is entirely unclear and is going to be very confusing rather than clarifying.

Comment: @Bill Woodger, no problem, I agree that the tag needs improving. Ideally I would like a new tag as well: A tag called RDi or ibm-rational-developer-for-i would be good as rational is more of a product family rather than a specific product. How can I request a new tag?

Comment: I've made a tag rational-developer-for-i. I had to drop the IBM because it made it too long. There is a rational-clearcase tag as well.

Comment: @Bill Woodger makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Being discussed on Meta here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345415/1927206. If you want to have another go at the wiki, take not of the rejection comments. Usage guidance is important. It is neither advertising, nor simple documentation. So, some description, how to use it, and a link. Don't just paste anything, people check for simple copying. Be accurate when using the tag. We do probably already need more looking at some of the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When the app is killed it's no longer running.

You can of course program parts of your app to run as a [background service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#WhatIsAService)